# Github action jobs triggered by different events

Tags: github-actions

My release pipeline in Github action has two jobs (1) Testing (2) Release

This is what I am aim to achieve:

The testing job of the release pipeline will be triggered by creating a pull-request, the release job of the pipeline will be rung when pull-request is merged

```
name: OC-API CD
on: 
  pull_request:
    types: [merged]
    branches: 
       - master

jobs:
  testing:
  runs-on: ubuntu-latest
  steps:
  ...

  release:
  runs-on: ubuntu-latest
  steps:
  ...
```

It seems all jobs has to be triggered by the same events via `on`,

(1) Is there any way that different job can be triggered by different events?

(2) How can I add dependency between testing and release, AKA, the release job is depend on the successfully runs the testing job

Comment: 1 - You can use an `if` condition at the job level, to run the job only if the condition is true. 2 - You can use the `needs` field at the job level to wait for a job to be executed before running another. Check the [workflow syntax for Github Actions](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions) 

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can control each job by adding `if`, in your case it will be like this:

```
jobs:
  testing:
  if: ${{ github.event.action }} == 'opened'
  runs-on: ubuntu-latest
  steps:
  ...
```

Keep in mind you have to add `opened` to a `on:  pull_request: types:`  array of course :)

For the second part you can add dependency using `needs`, like this:

```
jobs:
  testing:
  runs-on: ubuntu-latest
  steps:
  ...

  release:
  needs: testing
  runs-on: ubuntu-latest
  steps:
  ...
```

Comment: Is this suppose to be something like if: `${{ github.event.issue.pull_request }} == 'opened'`

Comment: @SLN not according to https://docs.github.com/en/developers/webhooks-and-events/events/github-event-types#pullrequestevent

Comment: You wrote "Keep in mind you have to `opened` to a `types` array of course". Did you mean to write "Keep in mind you have to **compare** `opened` to a `types` array, of course"?

Comment: @Alan I meant to "add" opened to `on:pull_requests:types` array